# Can I debug a JVM created in native code via JNI?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a C++ program that is creating a JVM using the JNI_CreateJavaVM() function.  The program is working great, but I'd like to be able to debug events in the Java code, e.g. add a breakpoint.  It seems the JDB debugging application has -attach and -connect parameters that might possibly be able to connect to the JVM I've created in native code.  Has anyone ever done this?  Can it be made to work?  Or, is there an alternative way to debug a JVM created in native code?

Thanks!
Dan

Answer (score 2):

If you can specify startup parameters of your JVM, you can open port for debug connections.

```
 -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009
```

Every Java IDE can utilize this protocol, see Run->Attach to local process in Intellij IDEA, for example.

Comment: Oh, that's excellent!  Am I correct then that I would use the Java Platform Debugger Architecture (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/) to communicate with the JVM?

Comment: Have you tried already to connect to your JVM with an external debugger or not?